# GitHub API: how efficiently get the total contributors amount per repository?

Tags: github-api

Is there a way to efficiently get the amount of all different contributors of a GitHub repository using the GitHub API?

I mean, without necessarily getting all the contributor objects and manually count the total amount.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution may be using [pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/).

When we use pagination, we get some information in the **Response Header** about the total amount of pages according to how many items per page we are requesting (using the `per_page` parameter).

So a trick could be requesting the list of contributors with one item per page:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contributors?per_page=1
```

doing this in our Response Header there will be a `Link` property with the following content:

> Link:https://api.github.com/repositories/ID/contributors?per_page=1&page=2;
>   rel="next",
>   https://api.github.com/repositories/ID/contributors?per_page=1&page=XXXXXXXX;
>   rel="last"

the XXXXXXXX value, just before `rel="last"` will be the total amount of pages, but since we are requesting one item per page, it will be also the total amount of contributors.

Comment: Would have been cool if it worked, but for example, for the URL https://api.github.com/repos/tensorflow/tensorflow/contributors?per_page=1, it shows last at 370, but the tensorflow web page shows more than 1600 contributors.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the trick is to request the list of contributors with one item per page. But include anon=true as a query param to include anonymous contributors as well

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contributors?per_page=1&anon=true
```

And in the response header (like it was mentioned in the previous answer), look for the Link property and get the value just before `rel="last"`

Comment: Is it possible to get the total number of contributors unique to a repository that is forked from a different repository?