# Github API: Fetching fill list of contributors returns wrong count

Tags: github, fetch-api, github-api

I found similar questions here but the answer in most of them is to add `anon=1` to the link.

I've done that and it still returns the wrong amount, is there anything I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
const API = 'https://api.github.com/repos/rust-lang/regex/stats/contributors?anon=1?per_page=100?page=5'

const getContributorsCount = async () => {
  const data: any = await axios
    .get(API)
    .then((res) => res.data.length);

  console.log(data)
};
```

I get in return `100` when the actual number is `147`.

Comment: And? Are you expecting to get something else by setting per_page=100? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347339/github-api-how-efficiently-get-the-total-contributors-amount-per-repository

Comment: @DmitriyMozgovoy didn't notice that, I've changed it to `per_page=1000` but it still shows me `100`

Comment: @DmitriyMozgovoy I don't get `rel` property in my headers response

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getContributorsCount(user, repo) {
  return axios.get(
    `https://api.github.com/repos/${encodeURIComponent(user)}/${encodeURIComponent(repo)}/contributors?per_page=1`
  ).then(({headers})=> {
    const link = headers.link && headers.link.split(';')[1];
    const match = link && /&page=(\d+)/.exec(link);
    return match && +match[1];
  })
}

console.log(`count: ${await getContributorsCount('axios', 'axios')}`); //343
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot, yet it still not accurate for some reason. I've tried adding `anon=1` to it but it still doesn't show the correct amount of users